# Using the Nativescript platform-specific project

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

To my understanding, Nativescript takes the javascript (or typescript) + nativescript code and creates project files for both android and ios in order to be able to run them as native apps. I also know that these files all seem to be located in the Resources directory. However when I try to run a simulator from the xcode project that is created, it fails.

I don't want to know how to fix the simulator failure, I just want to know if it's possible for a swift developer to take the xcode project created by Nativescript and continue developing as a regular native app.

If so, is this possible with the android project as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-nativescript-in-an-existing-native-ios-android-applications

The two articles explain in detail how you can embed the NativeScript runtimes in native Objective-C and Android applications.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out.